# add multiple chrome inline installations for different link tags same domain

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, inline

I have a Chrome extension, and a Chrome app. I need inline install for both of them on the same domain.

As per Googles instructions (for one inline install) I add the header link tag:

```
<link rel="chrome-webstore-item" href="https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/itemID">
```

Then add the onclick function in the body:

```
<button onclick="chrome.webstore.install()" id="install-button">Add to Chrome</button>
<script>
if (chrome.app.isInstalled) {
  document.getElementById('install-button').style.display = 'none';
}
</script>
```

What I need to know is how to add two instances. One for the extension, and one for the app. Do I add two link tags in the header, then edit the onclick function?

This is what Google says to do for multiple instances, but I don't understand where to edit the onclick function to differentiate between the two.

> To actually begin inline installation, the
>   chrome.webstore.install(url, successCallback, failureCallback)
>   function must be called. This function can only be called in response
>   to a user gesture, for example within a click event handler; an
>   exception will be thrown if it is not. The function can have the
>   following parameters:
>
> *url (optional string)* If you have more than one  tag on your
>   page with the chrome-webstore-item relation, you can choose which item
>   you'd like to install by passing in its URL here. If it is omitted,
>   then the first (or only) link will be used. An exception will be
>   thrown if the passed in URL does not exist on the page.
>
> *successCallback (optional function)* This function is invoked when
>   inline installation successfully completes (after the dialog is shown
>   and the user agrees to add the item to Chrome). You may wish to use
>   this to hide the user interface element that prompted the user to
>   install the app or extension.
>
> *failureCallback (optional function)* This
>   function is invoked when inline installation does not successfully
>   complete. Possible reasons for this include the user canceling the
>   dialog, the linked item not being found in the store, or the install
>   being initiated from a non-verified site. The callback is given a
>   failure detail string as a parameter. You may wish to inspect or log
>   that string for debugging purposes, but you should not rely on
>   specific strings being passed back.

I currently have one link tag in my header for the extension. I need to add another inline installation, on a different page, same domain, but this second onclick code needs to be different so it doesn't refer to the existing link tag in my header.

Many thanks.

Comment: @Xan. Much appreciated, but that is not what I'm trying to achieve. The 'extension' page has an inline install button which works just fine. I just need the other inline install button code for the app install to work. When I add a second link tag in the head, the app inline install button is pulling the extension inline link tag. I need just a slight change in the second inline install code the app, so that it won't confuse the link tags. I'm not concerned if the inline buttons show even if the user has them installed. I need the app inline button to point to the proper link tag in the head.

Comment: I'm not entirely sure this can be done. You may have to use two separate pages. Alternatively, maybe you can use an iframe for the second one and sneak it past Google's way overburdening security model?

Answer (score 1):

```
<link rel="chrome-webstore-item" href="https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/itemID1">
<link rel="chrome-webstore-item" href="https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/itemID2">

<button onclick="chrome.webstore.install('https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/itemID1')" id="install-button-1">Add App to Chrome</button>
<button onclick="chrome.webstore.install('https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/itemID2')" id="install-button-2">Add Extension to Chrome</button>
```

Comment: Doesn't work, but that definitely looks like it would, and should.

Answer (score 0):

The [very same docs page](https://developer.chrome.com/webstore/inline_installation#already-installed) shows a method for the extensions.

Basically, your extension can inject a `<div id="somethingYouExpect">` into the DOM, and the page's script can detect that.

It's a bit clunky though: I was trying to get it to work for test code and didn't manage to do so in a good way, as content scripts are injected either before DOM is constructed at all or after document ready fires. You can bypass that with mutation observers, but *meh* and your button will be visible for a split second.

You can save yourself some pain, if you're just hiding an element, by injecting a css file hiding it. Or, you can hide the elements from injected code. Either way is somewhat layout-sensitive though.

If you HAVE to be layout-independent and at the same time want something more complex than element hiding, either go the (div inject + mutation observer) route or you can try [`window.postMessage` approach](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/content_scripts#host-page-communication) to signal the page to hide the element.

### Step by step guide for the extension / CSS variant.

Suppose your extension install UI is contained in an element with id `extension-install`.

Add a content script to the manifest file:

```
"content_scripts": [
  {
    "matches": ["*://yourdomain/*"],
    "css": ["iaminstalled.css"],
    "run_at": "document_start"
  }
],
```

The CSS:

```
#extension-install {
  display: none !important;
}
```

### So, to recap:

- To allow installs of both the app and the extension, you need two `<link>` tags in the head
- To install either you pass the url parameter to `chrome.webstore.install`
- If **the app** is installed, it will define `chrome.app.isInstalled` in the page's context. You can check for it from the page to hide the install button.
- If **the extension** is installed, it can inject CSS/JS into page to hide the install button.